# Replacing text won't go correctly with encoding and decoding

Tags: arrays, swift, decode, encode

I am currently using 2 arrays:

```
let letters:[Character] =
    [" ","a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z","!","@","#","$","%","^","&","*","(",")","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0","A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","E","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"]
let cypher:[Character]  = ["o","p","q","r","a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","u","v","w","x","y","z","j","k","l","m","n","s","t","$","@","#","!","&","%","^","*","("," ",")","5","7","2","9","8","0","1","3","2","4","Q","W","E","R","T","Y","U","I","O","P","A","S","D","F","G","H","J","K","L","Z","X","C","V","B","N","M"]
```

Both 73 characters.

I am using this line of code to encode the inserted text:

```
    var encode:[Character:Character] = [:]

    for (index, letter) in letters.enumerated() { encode[letter] = cypher[index] }
    let encodeStep1 = String(insertedText.characters.map({ encode[$0] ?? $0 }))

    randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(9) + 1)
    var encodeStep2 = cypher.rotate(shift: randomNumber)

    for (index, letter) in letters.enumerated() { encode[letter] = encodeStep2[index] }
    let final = String(encodeStep1.characters.map({ encode[$0] ?? $0 }))
```

Decode:

```
 var decode:[Character:Character] = [:]

let step1 = cypher.rotate(shift: (randomNumber))
        for (index, letter) in step1.enumerated() { decode[letter] = letters[index] }
        let step1Decoded = String(insertedEncryptedText.characters.map({ decode[$0] ?? $0 }))

        for (index, letter) in cypher.enumerated() { decode[letter] = letters[index] }
        let step2Decoded = String(step1Decoded.characters.map({ decode[$0] ?? $0 }))
```

Rotate function:

```
extension Array {
    func rotate(shift:Int) -> Array {
        var array = Array()
        if (self.count > 0) {
            array = self
            if (shift > 0) {
                for i in 1...shift {
                    array.append(array.remove(at: 0))
                }
            }
            else if (shift < 0) {
                for i in 1...abs(shift) {
                    array.insert(array.remove(at: array.count-1),at:0)
                }
            }
        }
        return array
    }
}
```

For some very odd reason, number "3" is often shown as a number "9" when decoded. From what I have seen, the problem occurs at step2Decoded. I just can not figure out what I am doing wrong. This is however a part of the code, if I need to post more I can do that.

Comment: Where is the code for `rotate`? e.g. `cypher.rotate(shift: randomNumber)`

Comment: Hi Aaron, It's :

var decode:[Character:Character] = [:]

let step1 = cypher.rotate(shift: (randomNumber))
        for (index, letter) in step1.enumerated() { decode[letter] = letters[index] }
        let step1Decoded = String(insertedEncryptedText.characters.map({ decode[$0] ?? $0 }))

        for (index, letter) in cypher.enumerated() { decode[letter] = letters[index] }
        let step2Decoded = String(step1Decoded.characters.map({ decode[$0] ?? $0 }))

Comment: OP: Aaron has provided a plausible answer -- if correct, you should accept it; if incorrect, comment on his answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you have a typo. Your `cypher` array has two "2"s in it, one at `cypher[39]` and another 6 indices further at `cypher[45]`. When you're decoding in the final step you're expecting `decoded["2"]` to map to the value "3" in the `letters` array, which it does, but it's getting overwritten when it hits the "2" again setting it to the value 6 indices further in the `letters` array which has a value of "9".

I assume you want to change that second "2" value in the `letters` array to "6" instead (since I noticed there was no "6" in there). That would solve your problem.